# Access 2016 VBA TextBox is Null

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I don't use VBA from long time....I have this form in Access 2016

[image]

When I try to access to the various TextBoxes through the Me.Controls Collection and convert it to a TextBox object, I get a Null reference **but some its properties are valid (eg. tb.Name)**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim ctrl As Control
  Dim tb As TextBox
  Dim evTb As clsEventTextBox

  Set m_TbColl = New Collection

  For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If Left$(ctrl.Name, 4) = "Txt_" Then
      Set tb = ctrl
      'Create the TextBox wrapper 
      Set evTb = New clsEventTextBox
      Set evTb.EventsHandler = Me

      Set evTb.InnerTextBox = tb  <----- HERE tb Is NULL

      m_TbColl.Add evTb, ctrl.Name
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

I miss something?
Also, is there a way to get the Type of a Control instead of using

```
Left$(ctrl.Name, 4) = "Txt_"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the type, use `TypeName` like this:

```
If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
```

And to ensure `tb` takes the form of a `Textbox` object, use this

```
Set tb = Controls(ctrl.Name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown the class that you're using, but assuming it looks something like this:

```
Private WithEvents f_EH As Access.Form
Private WithEvents f_TB As Access.TextBox

Public Property Set EventsHandler(frm As Access.Form)
  Set f_EH = frm
End Property

Public Property Set InnerTextBox(ctl As Access.TextBox)
   Set f_TB = ctl
End Property
```

If I use a class with that structure, the code in your post works fine. But notice that I've explicitly set the expected type of the `InnerTextBox` property to `Access.TextBox`.

But your code does needless casting, uses Hungarian naming (yuck!), and relies on the first 4 characters of the name being "Txt_" and could be written as:

```
  Dim ctrl As Control
  Dim evTb As clsEventTextBox

  Set m_TbColl = New Collection

  For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Access.TextBox Then
      'Create the TextBox wrapper
      Set evTb = New clsEventTextBox
      Set evTb.EventsHandler = Me

      Set evTb.InnerTextBox = ctrl  'Just pass the ctrl reference without casting

      m_TbColl.Add evTb, ctrl.Name
    End If
  Next
```

Note the use of `TypeOf` in `If TypeOf ctrl Is Access.TextBox Then` to determine whether the control is a `TextBox`.

Comment: thanks, my mistake was to have forgot the 'Set' in InnerTextBox Set property :(  
Little OT: I have post another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219351/access-2016-set-control-events-at-runtime) can you know why that happens?